# JS: change color square on canvas with just javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, colors

I'm tryin to change color on my squares without using jquery or CSS.
How can I change simultaneously all square color?

P.s.: I'm new in HTML5+JS. 
Using this code I can change square color after click on the button. But I'd like to have a button that can change all squares already presented on canvas area.

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Paint Canvas</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
        <canvas id="imageView" width="600" height="300" onclick="createRect(red, 20,20);"/>     
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Green" id="green" onclick="GreenRect()">
    <input type="button" value="Red" id="red" onclick="RedRect()">
    <input type="button" value="clear canvas" id="clear" onclick="ImgClr()">        
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
canvas {  border: 1px solid black;}
```

**JavaScript**

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("imageView");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");      
    function createCircle(){        
    }    
    function createRect(fillColor, w, h) {
        context.fillStyle = fillColor;
        x = event.pageX; 
        y = event.pageY;
        context.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
    }       
    function GreenRect () {
        context.fillStyle= 'green';
        context.stroke();
    }    
    function RedRect () {
        context.fillStyle= 'red';
        context.stroke();
    }    
    function ImgClr () {
        context.clearRect(0,0, 600, 300);  
    }
```

Comment: Create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas squares you are drawing are not "Objects" like in Javascript.

You cannot change their color, technically speaking.

What you can do, though, is redraw them all with another color. Which is what I suggest.
You have the right parameter here:
`function createRect(fillColor, w, h)`

So you just want to do a `createRect('red', ...)`

Comment: Think of the canvas as a table. When drawing something on it, it's like picking a shape, putting it in ink, and then pressing it on the table. You can't change the ink color, but you can put your shape in another ink color and press it on the table at the same position than the first time.